# Trouble with AngularJS and Select binding not loading default values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I am having trouble with a `<select>` input and binding with AngluarJS. I've created a minimum working sample on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/P4T25RoJrU4mvbBiUJ9S?p=preview.

The basic issue is as follows: the value in the dropdown is never pre-selected with the value from my model.

Additionally, in Angular 1.1.5, `ng-options` appears to not include a "label" on the generated `<option>` tags, so when you change selection the drop down control doesn't register any change.

Comment: If you remove the "track by option.id" from the ng-options, it should pre-select based on your model. I have the modified Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/b4ddyA5Q4jGNcJI1d8eW?p=preview

Comment: yeah, I tried, I got nothing...

Comment: @VivekN That seems to have fixed my problem. Thank you very much. Post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- Compare strings to strings
- Be careful when using `select as` and `track by` in the same expression.

JS

```
angular.module('defaultValueSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     availableOptions: [
       {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
       {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
       {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
     ],
     //USE this
     selectedOption: '2'
     //NOT this
     //selectedOption: 2 //This sets the default value
     };
 }]);
```

HTML

```
<!-- remove 'track by option.id' -->

<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
    ng-options="option.id as option.name for option 
                in data.availableOptions track by option.id"
    ng-model="data.selectedOption">
</select>
```

From the Docs:

> Be careful when using `select as` and `track by` in the same expression.
>
> This will work:
>
> ```
> <select 
>     ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id"
>     ng-model="selected">
> </select>
> ```
>
> but this will not work:
>
> ```
> <select 
>     ng-options="item.subItem as item.label for item in items track by item.id"
>     ng-model="selected">
> </select>
> ```

-- [AngularJS `ng-options` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 1):

As requested by OP, adding the comment as the answer.

If you remove the "track by option.id" from the ng-options as following, it should pre-select based on your model.

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
      ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in data.availableOptions"
      ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
```

Check out the modified Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/b4ddyA5Q4jGNcJI1d8eW?p=preview