# How can i change a row in table after ng-repeat with filter

Tags: angularjs

I'm making UI like Excel. But i have a big trouble.

I need when i click to `update` button, and only THIS row in table change template to edit (like

to  ...). But i cannot do it.
Thai is my way:

```
<tbody dir-paginate="student in ClassStudents | filter: search | itemsPerPage: 20 track by $index">
    <tr ng-show="NormalMode">
        <td>{{student.Student.StudentName}}</td>

        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Detail</button>
            <button ng-click="updateEvent($index)" class="btn btn-primary">
              Update
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="EditorMode">
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="student.Student.StudentName"></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

In my AngularJS Controller, i dont know how to write it for true. Can you help me to do this UI? So many thanks!

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the `ng-click` handler pass the item as an argument instead of `$index`:

```
̶<̶t̶b̶o̶d̶y̶ ̶d̶i̶r̶-̶p̶a̶g̶i̶n̶a̶t̶e̶=̶"̶s̶t̶u̶d̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶C̶l̶a̶s̶s̶S̶t̶u̶d̶e̶n̶t̶s̶ ̶|̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶t̶e̶r̶:̶ ̶s̶e̶a̶r̶c̶h̶ ̶|̶ ̶i̶t̶e̶m̶s̶P̶e̶r̶P̶a̶g̶e̶:̶ ̶2̶0̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶"̶>̶
<tbody dir-paginate="student in ClassStudents | filter: search | itemsPerPage: 20">
    <tr ng-show="NormalMode">
        <td>{{student.Student.StudentName}}</td>

        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Detail</button>
            ̶<̶b̶u̶t̶t̶o̶n̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶=̶"̶u̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶E̶v̶e̶n̶t̶(̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶)̶"̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶=̶"̶b̶t̶n̶ ̶b̶t̶n̶-̶p̶r̶i̶m̶a̶r̶y̶"̶>̶
            <button ng-click="updateEvent(student)" class="btn btn-primary">
              Update
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The filter in the `ng-repeat` causes `$index` of the view to differ from the index of the item in the `ClassStudents` array. Instead, pass the actual item to the `updateItem` function.

Also it is not wise to use `track by $index` when the list contains objects filtered from an array. See [When not to use 'track by $index' in an AngularJS ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720622/when-not-to-use-track-by-index-in-an-angularjs-ng-repeat/45723356#45723356).