# Angularjs Select option Performance Improvement - Gropup By Filter for 3000+ datas

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am having select dropdown which filters data corresponding to selected option. If nothing is selected then it shows 3000+ records which is freezing my UI for few seconds. But for other option switching which has few hundreds data is perfect and fast. Is there any way to improve performance here?

Following is the dropdown filter and citylist is an array which gets datas from server.

```
Select City:<span class="float-right fa fa-window-close mb-2"
                  ng-click="sm.selectedCity=undefined;">
            </span>
<select ng-model="sm.selectedCity" >
    <option value="" selected hidden />
    <option ng-repeat="s in sm.citylist"
            ng-selected="sm.selectedCity" ng-value="">
      {{s.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Following UI data varies based on selected city option above. Initially none of the option is selected which fetches more than 3000 datas for one of the grouped Country object.

To briefly explain below UI...sampledata is a complex object filled from server. sampledata contains Country property which is grouped and it can be collapsed or expanded by clicking plus/minus at its right side. Based on selected city filter Grouped Country will change. Its working fine for less data. But if one of the Country has more datas like (3000+) my UI freezes while clearing the filter

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in sm.sampledata | filter:{STFilter:sm.selectedCity} | filter:{someother } | filter:search.number  | orderBy:'Country' | groupBy: 'Country' track by $index">
      <div class="mb-5">
          {{ key }} ({{ value.length }})<span ng-class="sm.toggle[$index] === true ? 'fa fa-minus' : 'fa fa-plus'" ng-click="sm.toggle[$index] = !sm.toggle[$index]" class="pull-right"></span>
      </div>

      <div ng-show="sm.toggle[$index]">
          <div ng-repeat="o in value">
              //o is a complex object in which one of the object needs to be filtered based on selected option from dropdown
              <div>
                  {{o.sample1}}<span class="pull-right">{{o.sample2}}</span>
              </div>
              //Still more will come
          </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
</div>
```

Note: I am using angular 1.7.2 version

Comment: May have to implement a custom `select` for that 3000 one and lazy load as the user scrolls. Since there's no way for the user to see all 3000 options at once, there's no reason for the view to bind them all initially.

Comment: **Note:** `ngSelected` does not interact with the `select` and `ngModel` directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you are using `ngModel` on the select, you should not use `ngSelected` on the options, as `ngModel` will set the select value and selected options. [1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected#overview)

Comment: **Best Practice:** If you are working with objects that have a unique identifier property, you should track by this identifier instead of the object instance, e.g. `item in items track by item.id`. Should you reload your data later, ngRepeat will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones. **For large collections, this significantly improves rendering performance.** [2](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)

Comment: @georgeawg I removed ng-selected and its working fine with ng-model. Thanks for the suggestion. I already used track by in the code. You could see it if you scroll to the right side of the sample code above. Is that right way to implement that?? I don't have unique id hence used $index.

Comment: Using `track by $index` with collections of objects is not advised. See [When not to use 'track by $index' in an AngularJS ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720622/when-not-to-use-track-by-index-in-an-angularjs-ng-repeat/45723356#45723356).

Comment: 3000 options? Not even mentioning the performance issues you will trigger with all the bindings it is not a good design. You could go for a search input and slide a few suggestions in on request.

Answer (score 0):

To increase performance, use the [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive.

From the Docs:

> ## Choosing between `ngRepeat` and `ngOptions`
>
> In many cases, `ngRepeat` can be used on `<option>` elements instead of `ngOptions` to achieve a similar result. However, `ngOptions` provides some benefits:
>
> - more flexibility in how the `<select>`'s model is assigned via the select as part of the comprehension expression
> - **reduced memory consumption** by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance
> - **increased render speed** by creating the options in a documentFragment instead of individually
>
> Specifically, select with **repeated options slows down significantly starting at 2000 options** in Chrome and Internet Explorer / Edge.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference - Choosing between `ngRepeat` and `ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#choosing-between-ngrepeat-and-ngoptions-)
- [AngularJS `ng-options` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

---

```
Select City:<span class="float-right fa fa-window-close mb-2"
                  ng-click="sm.selectedCity=null">
            </span>
<select ng-model="sm.selectedCity" 
        ng-options="s.value as s.value for s in sm.selectedCity">
</select>
```

Comment: After changing ng-repeat to ng-options filter is not working. Its not showing grouped country for the selected city