# Use ng-repeat and $index to set the model property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can I use ng-repeat and $index to set a model property dynamically?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(10) track by $index">
  <input ng-model="model.prop{{$index}}">    
</div>
```

And I want my model to end up like this (i.e. so these properties don't exist in the controller code, I want them to be dynamically added):

```
{
  "prop0": "val",
  "prop1": "val",
  "prop2": "val",
  "prop3": "val",
  "prop4": "val",
...
  "prop10": "val"

  "otherProperty": "xxx"
}
```

I don't want the properties to be an array and I need to do this without changes to the controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted, I did this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(10) track by $index">
  <input ng-model="model.['prop' + ($index)]">    
</div>
```

Comment: this worked for you? did you have to create some sort of directive? id love to see your controller. do you think you can explain your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate object (key, value) in directive `ng-repeat`

**Controller**

```
$scope.props = {
  "prop0": "val",
  "prop1": "val",
  "prop2": "val",
  "prop3": "val",
  "prop4": "val",
...
  "prop10": "val"
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in props">
  <input ng-model="props[key]">    
</div>
```

In some cases you should avoid using `track by $index` please check [Tracking and Duplicates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) in AngularJs doc and [When not to use 'track by $index' in an AngularJS ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720622/when-not-to-use-track-by-index-in-an-angularjs-ng-repeat) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi @Abinesh Joyel, very close I've changed my question slightly